# aspnet website where to put my log text file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an aspnet website and i have a log text file in the main root directory of the site but the log is always empty (I think it cant write the file)

Should i put the file in the app_data folder and recompile or should I give some permission to the file?

Are there some security issues?

Thank you

Comment: please show us the code for writing your log file.

Comment: In local it works, on server it seems not

Comment: I suggest that you put the log file in its own directory in the website directory. That way, if, for example, you later decide to have a new log file every day then they are all contained neatly. You can also, in IIS Manager, easily set the directory to not be served so that the log files are not visible to anyone via the website.

Comment: Do you have the log-file-writing code in a Try...Catch? If so, you are probably hiding the error message which would be shown if the code could not write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

root directory is inside the c:/ drive so you have to give permission to that file to write.

or you can put that in any other drive so it will not ask any permission.

Comment: Which permission? Are there security issues with the first approach?